# Foreign key declaration can be replaced by its equivalent check constraint True or False?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I wanna know that a foreign key declaration can be replaced by its equivalent check constraint.. If yes why? I tried to google it but couldn't find the answer
Word of advice please...

Comment: What is the check constraint you had in mind?

Comment: Foreign keys are a kind of contraints that you may have on your DB

Comment: It limits the range of values to be inserted in a single column.
If you define a 'CHECK' constraint on a table it can limit the values in certain columns based on values in other columns in the row.@Dan

Comment: A check constraint doesn't need to consider more than one column. For example, `CHECK (this_column between 1 and 50)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can replace `foreign key` with `check` constraint but remember to use [Enums](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

Comment: An enum is neither a foreign key nor a check constraint. In fact, enums have nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by *replaced*.

At the conceptual level, you can consider a foreign key constraint to be roughly a set of valid values. And, at the conceptual level, you can consider an equivalent check constraint to be roughly a set of valid values.

If that's *all* you mean by *replaced*, then you can replace a foreign key constraint with an equivalent check constraint.

But the set of valid values for a foreign key constraint can be changed with SQL DML: SQL insert, update, delete statements. The set of valid values for an equivalent check constraint cannot be changed that way. You have to use SQL DDL to change a check constraint.

Also, different users might have different privileges on the referenced table of a foreign key constraint. Some might have only insert privileges, some might have insert and update privileges, etc. You can't control changes to a check constraint that way. A user that's allowed to change the check constraint can change it in any way.